# Tensorflow GCP online Endpoint prediction instance Key and values format

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

Running a time series analysis on Iowa liquor sales data.
I am able to train the model using TensorFlow and deployed it to an endpoint

As per the GCP docs, I am referring to this code sample to invoke an API endpoint for prediction:

https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/master/samples/snippets/predict_custom_trained_model_sample.py

I am running into an issue where no matter how I enter instance values I am running into formatting errors.

currently the way I am calling the method is :

```
 predict_custom_trained_model_sample(
    project="XXXX",
    endpoint_id="YYY",
    location="us-central1",
    instance_dict={ "instances":[
                                    {
                                    "date" : '03-10-2021',
                                    "store_name" : "CENTRAL CITY LIQUOR, INC.",
                                    "category_name" : "IMPORTED DISTILLED SPIRIT SPECIALTY",
                                    "vendor_name" : "JINRO AMERICA INC",
                                    "item_description" : "JINRO CHAMISUL FRESH SOJU"
                                    }
                                ]})
```

The error I am getting :

```
InvalidArgument: 400 Failed to handle request. endpoint_id: xxxxx, deployed_model_id: xxxxx with error: `{
    "error": "Failed to process element: 0 key: instances of 'instances' list. Error: Invalid argument: JSON object: does not have named input: instances"
}`
```

I am trying to run the prediction on a single item value. Can someone point to the right syntax or if there are any other deeper issues to my problem?

Comment: I tried this on a custom model of mine and got the same error. Though, I can predict using the UI of AI Platform Unified. I'll further check on this as well.

Comment: Interesting, we are getting the error on the UI as well.

Comment: You can contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures#create_a_support_case) if you are still experiencing this error.

Comment: yes currently the case is open with the support team , will update the output here

Answer (score 1):

From the example, I understand that the instance_dict contain only the array of instance and not the `instances` key

```
 predict_custom_trained_model_sample(
    project="XXXX",
    endpoint_id="YYY",
    location="us-central1",
    instance_dict=[
      {
        "date" : '03-10-2021',
        "store_name" : "CENTRAL CITY LIQUOR, INC.",
        "category_name" : "IMPORTED DISTILLED SPIRIT SPECIALTY",
        "vendor_name" : "JINRO AMERICA INC",
        "item_description" : "JINRO CHAMISUL FRESH SOJU"
      }
    ])
```

Comment: I have tried the array structure as well but still no luck !!

Comment: Stil the same error tried multiple combinations, the endpoint is up and running but I keep getting keys not being recognized

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this instead? From looking at the code, looks like it only accepts one instance that needs to be a Dict:

```
 predict_custom_trained_model_sample(
    project="XXXX",
    endpoint_id="YYY",
    location="us-central1",
    instance_dict={
        "date" : '03-10-2021',
        "store_name" : "CENTRAL CITY LIQUOR, INC.",
        "category_name" : "IMPORTED DISTILLED SPIRIT SPECIALTY",
        "vendor_name" : "JINRO AMERICA INC",
        "item_description" : "JINRO CHAMISUL FRESH SOJU"
    })
```

Comment: InvalidArgument: 400 Failed to handle request. endpoint_id: YYYYYYY , deployed_model_id: XXXXXX with error: {
    "error": "Failed to process element: 0 key: category_name of 'instances' list. Error: Invalid argument: JSON object: does not have named input: category_name"
}                       

Seems like not able to identify the dickt keys or some schema mismatch is happening